# Best way to use shouldque

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5.4

I was wondering where in the cycle is the best way to use ques for the best result.

1. I have a `controller` that creates an object
2. An `observer` is watching for the created method and fires an event
3. The `event` saves the the model and pushes it into a broadcast channel
4. A `listener` creates a notification
5. The `notification` will store it in a database and send an email

On the one hand I want to use less time so the response for the user is really quick, but on the other hand I don't want that the broadcast takes to long.

So I thought my listener class has to implement the `ShouldQueue` class, but has the notification class also to implement it?

Comment: I don't get the last paragraph

Comment: if your event is queued, you needn't queue your notification class. you can also prioritize your queue so that the event/notification queue(if you decide to create one) jumps ahead of other process in queue.